# Why does activating conda environment work in command prompt but not in the terminal in Atom or VS Code (windows)?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, atom-editor, development-environment

I downloaded and installed anaconda, and I am able to create an environment and activate it within the normal windows command prompt. However, when I try to activate it within the terminal in Atom or VS Code (using windows computer), [nothing happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J49yy.png)

how can I get the development environment to activate within this terminal?

Comment: Have you tried activating the env via `your-env\scripts\activate.bat`? In vscode you can also try to set `"python.pythonPath"` in your settings.json (workspace settings, if you don't want it globally) then open a python script and  finally open a new terminal. the env should be activated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If everything works fine under Command Prompt then you can try using it under VS Code with the following setting:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
```